# Java & Spring - polling the http endpoint until the server finishes processing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, polling

I'm struggling with picking up the right way to poll server with constant interval (eg ~1 second).

The flow goes as follows

- client application receives message, that indicates the polling could start with provided parameters (it doesn't poll when there is no need to)
- client application starts polling the http endpoint every ~1second with parameters arrived with message (like query parameter)
- server application responds with status **pending** so that indicates the client should continue polling
- server application responds with status **finished** and returns the result - there is no need to keep polling.

We can have multiple threads, as the client application might receive multiple message in the short time - polling should start immediately

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, maybe there is a proper tool that works with java/spring that I can use?

Key features

- poll only when there is a need to
- poll with custom parameters (custom params in a query string)
- scale polling as the application could poll multiple endpoints simultaneously with the same interval

I was going through various libs like Apache Camel or Spring Integration PollableChannel, but I feel like none of these is going to give me the right solution out of the box.

If there is no lib like this - I'm going to write it on my own using redis and simple loop, but maybe someone has faced similar problem.

Comment: have you thought about avoiding polling and using a WebSocket to provide a sort of callback mechanism?

Comment: I'm afraid server application does not support WebSocket protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your architecture correctly, the point is to call the same HTTP endpoint from the client application until expected result. In this case I would suggest something like `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` with an `AlwaysRetryPolicy` and a `FixedBackOffPolicy` (1 second by default).

To simulate an exception I would suggest an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with the `propagateOnSuccessEvaluationFailures = true` option to re-throw an exception from the `onSuccessExpression` when reply from the server is `pending`.

Both of these advises (in the exact `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`, `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`) you need to apply to `@ServiceActivator` for the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`.

See more info in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Comment: Yes, the architecture is designed exactly as you understood. Is it going to support multiple pollers at the same time? I mean, when I receive event with id 1, I need to poll service.com/result-1.xml, If I receive event with id 2 I need to poll service.com/result-2.xml independently at the same time, until both satisfied. Thanks!

Comment: That's correct. Both of them are going to work in their own caller's threads, therefore this is fine to have concurrent requests for different parameters. Only the problem with mentioned solution that callers are going to be blocked until the proper `finished` response.